# How to achieve a inline full width div with border bottom

Tags: html, css

For instance its a from we have questions on the left and blank spaces that are filled dynamically on the right:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #left {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }

        #right {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #00FF00;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
       <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto"> right</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above renders well but the border bottom does not stick to the right div

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a container as LSE mentioned is probably the best way to do it, a cheap trick could be to do:

```
#left{
border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

but as I said, it works visually but it is not very elegant.

Comment: thanks for you contribution it works 100%...but how can i achieve this with out flex box..am rendering this on a pdf with Laravel dompdf and it does not support flex box

Comment: This does not require flexbox, it works with the code you provided. Just add my line to the #left selector so it gives you
`#left {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            border-bottom:1px solid red;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

#right p {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p> right</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you also need the text `right` to be on the edge, try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

#right p {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p> right</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you contribution it works 100%...but how can i achieve this with out flex box..am rendering this on a pdf with Laravel dompdf and it does not support flex box

Comment: @DennisGithinjiWakahia Without flexbox, I would just do what Dendenzilla suggested. Just add his css to your current code, without using flexbox.

Comment: I fully understand you but I just  need as it appears in the code snippet the background colors are not important I just need to  underline the green part (right) until the end of the div without underlining the blue part (left) without using flexbox